# How do I create CloudWatch Alarms for DocumentDB in Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, aws-documentdb, cloudwatch-alarms

How do I create Cloudwatch alarms in Cloudformation for AWS DocumentDB. There are no examples available. How to add CPU Utilization alarm on Primary vs Reader instances ?

I have tried creating an alarm, but faced issues with differentiating between the Primary vs Reader instance.

Can anyone please share a sample yaml/json cloudformation - to build such an alarm.

Answer (score 0):

To create an alarm for CPU utilization on DocumentDB primary and reader instances using AWS CloudFormation, you could use the following script:

```yaml
Resources:
  DocumentDBPrimaryCPUAlarm:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
    Properties:
      AlarmDescription: CPU utilization is high on the DocumentDB primary instance
      ComparisonOperator: GreaterThanThreshold
      EvaluationPeriods: 1
      MetricName: CPUUtilization
      Namespace: AWS/RDS
      Period: 60
      Statistic: Average
      Threshold: 90
      ActionsEnabled: true
      AlarmActions:
        - arn:aws:sns:<region>:<account-id>:<sns-topic-name>
      Dimensions:
        - Name: DBInstanceIdentifier
          Value: <documentdb-primary-instance-id>

  DocumentDBReaderCPUAlarm:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
    Properties:
      AlarmDescription: CPU utilization is high on the DocumentDB reader instance
      ComparisonOperator: GreaterThanThreshold
      EvaluationPeriods: 1
      MetricName: CPUUtilization
      Namespace: AWS/RDS
      Period: 60
      Statistic: Average
      Threshold: 90
      ActionsEnabled: true
      AlarmActions:
        - arn:aws:sns:<region>:<account-id>:<sns-topic-name>
      Dimensions:
        - Name: DBInstanceIdentifier
          Value: <documentdb-reader-instance-id>
```

The above YAML creates two alarms: one for the primary DocumentDB instance and one for the reader instance. The alarms monitor the CPU utilization and will trigger an SNS notification if the utilization goes above 90%.